# Scaling fonts document-wide

Tags: fonts, fontsize, scaling, typewriter

I'm looking to use `lcmtt` mentioned [here](http://www.tug.dk/FontCatalogue/lcmtt/) as my default typewriter font, but the scaling is way out of proportion with the rest of the text. I've used the following commands to enable the font:

```
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\renewcommand*\ttdefault{lcmtt}
```

How can I scale down this `\tt` font document wide?

...sorry if this is trivial, but I can't seem to crack it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You could use `\DeclareFontShape` for the scaling. Example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\makeatletter
\DeclareFontFamily{T1}{lcmtt}{\hyphenchar\font\m@ne}
\makeatother
\renewcommand*\ttdefault{lcmtt}
\DeclareFontShape{T1}{lcmtt}{m}{n}{%
  <13.82><16.59><10.8><23.89><28.66><34.4><41.28>%
  ecltt8}{}
\begin{document}
Text \texttt{Text}
\end{document}
```

Here I changed only the original value found in `t1lcmtt.fd` from 19.907 to 10.8, the rest I kept unchanged. Adjust this value 10.8 to see the scaling change.

[image: roman and typewriter]

Answer (score 6):

Using the [`anyfontsize` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/anyfontsize):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}% http://ctan.org/pkg/fontenc
\usepackage{anyfontsize}% http://ctan.org/pkg/anyfontsize
\begin{document}
This is regular text. \texttt{This is typewriter text.} \par
\renewcommand*\ttdefault{lcmtt}
This is regular text. \texttt{This is typewriter text.}
\end{document}
```