# Document-wide resize of a particular font

Tags: fonts, formatting, fontsize, sourcecodepro

I'm currently using the `sourcecodepro` package, and I've noticed that the text appears a bit big compared to usual text. Is there any way I can resize it to match the size of the text? I've had a look at [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/33333/scaling-fonts-document-wide) answer but I don't know how to adapt it to `sourcecodepro`.

Here's an MWE for demonstration:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{palatino, sourcecodepro}

\begin{document}
     The {\tt Person} class contains two {\tt String}s, the {\tt name} and {\tt surname}.
\end{document}
```

Which produces:
[image]

I appreciate any help.

Comment: Like many good font packages `sourcecodepro` supports the `scale` option to scale the font a bit: `\usepackage[scale=0.9]{sourcecodepro}` you'll probably have to play around with the value a bit.

Comment: @moewe I had no idea, thanks! Can you post it as an answer so I accept it?

Comment: Note that the `palatino` package is obsolete now and `mathpazo` is recommended instead: https://ctan.org/pkg/palatino-nfss

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Many (not all mind you) font package have an option called `scale` or `scaled` to scale the loaded font by a factor.

`sourcecodepro` seems to be a well-written package and indeed supports `scale`/`scaled` (both names are valid).

The exact value will depend on your tastes, but you can start with

```
\usepackage[scale=0.94]{sourcecodepro}
```

---

If you use LuaTeX or XeTeX with `fontspec` you can try to let `fontspec` figure out a good scaling factor automatically

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{TeX Gyre Pagella}
\setmonofont{SourceCodePro}[Scale=MatchLowercase]

\begin{document}
     The \texttt{Person} class contains two \texttt{String}s, the \texttt{name} and \texttt{surname}.
\end{document}
```

With `Scale=MatchLowercase` the factor is about 0.94, with `Scale=MatchUppercase` around 1.04.

Comment: `\tt` has been deprecated for more than twenty years.

Comment: @egreg Fair point. I hadn't really noticed it. Thanks for editing that.